# background-color on an option element not working in firefox 49.0.1

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-select, background-color

Below is an example of my code. It has always worked in the past, but it seems with the new Firefox update(49.0.1), it just appears as white. The html editor in the developer tools of Firefox has the below code as well. This seems to me like a bug, but I figured I'd post a question here to see if anyone knows how to fix the bug. I've also posted images of Firefox(the first one) and chrome.

```html
<select name="bom_bg_color_195898" id="bom_bg_color_195898" onchange="set_bom_bg(this,'195898');" class="unlocked">
  <option selected="" value="FFFFFF" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"></option>
  <option value="FF3333" style="background-color:#FF3333;"></option>
  <option value="99CCFF" style="background-color:#99CCFF;"></option>
  <option value="CC99FF" style="background-color:#CC99FF;"></option>
  <option value="FF99CC" style="background-color:#FF99CC;"></option>
  <option value="FFCC99" style="background-color:#FFCC99;"></option>
  <option value="FFFF99" style="background-color:#FFFF99;"></option>
  <option value="99FF99" style="background-color:#99FF99;"></option>
</select>
```

[image: Firefox]

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I've fixed this issue on my own and forgot to post an answer. It appears to be an issue with Firefox's new E10's upgrade. You can look at this site to see how to disable the upgrade. http://www.ghacks.net/2016/07/22/multi-process-firefox/

Comment: I have another weird situation: My firefox knows browser.tabs.remote.autostart and browser.tabs.remote.autostart2.
The first one browser.tabs.remote.autostart was already set to false.
Setting browser.tabs.remote.autostart2 to false fixed the background colors! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the exact same trouble.

**What I figured out:**
On first startup after creating a new Firefox profile, the background colors appear correctly.
After restarting Firefox, the background colors of the option fields are gone...

**Find the malicious config**
Next I tried to delete single config files from the profile. (On startup these are recreated).
In the end all config files were deleted and recreated but the backgrounds were still missing. I had to remove the complete profile folder in order to have the colors working again (only on first startup of course).